# Error when loading a template .pptx using ReporteRs package

Tags: r, templates, reporters

I'd like to automate the creation of powerpoint reports using a template.  According to ReporteRs documentation, that is done with:

```
doc = pptx(template = '/path/to/template.pptx')
```

Even when attempting to load the simplest of templates I get the following error:

```
Error in pptx(template = '/path/to/template.pptx') : 
  an error occured - code[LOADDOC_ERROR].
```

Even the minimal example on the CRAN reference for ReporteRs results in an error for me.  Here's the [pdf](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ReporteRs/ReporteRs.pdf) reference and below is the example located on page 86.  They first created a simple template called "template_example.pptx", then loaded the template, and made a small change to a slide.  I can create the template without error, but as soon as I try to load the new template, I get the error mentioned before.

```
# create an doc to be used as template later
mydoc = pptx( )
mydoc = addSlide( mydoc, slide.layout = "Title and Content")
mydoc = addTitle( mydoc, "a table")
mydoc = addFlexTable( mydoc, ft1 )
mydoc = addSlide( mydoc, slide.layout = "Title and Content")
mydoc = addTitle( mydoc, "some text")
mydoc = addParagraph( mydoc, "text example" )
writeDoc( mydoc, "template_example.pptx" )

# use file pp_template_example.pptx as template
# and replace slide 1
mydoc = pptx(template = "template_example.pptx" )
mydoc = addSlide( mydoc, slide.layout = "Title and Content", bookmark = 1)
mydoc = addTitle( mydoc, "a new table")
mydoc = addFlexTable( mydoc, ft2 )
writeDoc( mydoc, "slide_replacement.pptx" )
```

Does anyone have insight for why this error is occurring?   Thanks.

EDIT:  Adding `SessionInfo()` output.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.10.3 (Yosemite)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_1.0.1        lubridate_1.3.3      DT_0.1               readr_0.2.2          dplyr_0.4.3          shinydashboard_0.5.1
[7] rga_0.8              httr_1.0.0           jsonlite_0.9.16      RCurl_1.95-4.7       bitops_1.0-6         openxlsx_3.0.0      
[13] shiny_0.12.2         RAdwords_0.1.6       rJava_0.9-7          ReporteRs_0.8.2      ReporteRsjars_0.0.2 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_0.11.6      plyr_1.8.3       tools_3.2.2      digest_0.6.8     memoise_0.2.1    gtable_0.1.2     DBI_0.3.1        rstudioapi_0.3.1
[9] yaml_2.1.13      parallel_3.2.2   proto_0.3-10     stringr_1.0.0    htmlwidgets_0.5  grid_3.2.2       R6_2.1.1         reshape2_1.4.1  
[17] magrittr_1.5     scales_0.2.5     htmltools_0.2.6  MASS_7.3-43      assertthat_0.1   mime_0.3         colorspace_1.2-6 xtable_1.7-4    
[25] httpuv_1.3.3     labeling_0.3     stringi_0.5-5    lazyeval_0.1.10  munsell_0.4.2    rjson_0.2.15
```

Comment: Could you add your `sessionInfo()`? I can't reproduce the error...

Comment: `sessionInfo()` added

Comment: Can you open the first one (template_example.pptx)? The message is indicating the document is existing but cannot be loaded.

Comment: Yes, I can open the file, but cannot load it.

Comment: OK. For now, I don't have any clue on how to reproduce that issue...

Comment: Well I appreciate the effort!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97542/discussion-between-david-gohel-and-adam-birenbaum).

Comment: Hello there, I am having the exact same issue so please make sure to share your solution :)

Comment: No solution for now as I don't know how to reproduce. Any clue is welcome :)

Comment: What is your java version? `java -version`

Comment: I actually had to download an older version just to be able to install the package, but according to your documentation 1.6 is fine. Here it is: `java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-468-11M4833)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-468, mixed mode)`

Comment: I have created a git issue there: https://github.com/davidgohel/ReporteRs/issues/101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone has this issue, follow @David Gohel's advice --> https://github.com/davidgohel/ReporteRs/issues/101

davidgohel commented on Dec 23, 2015
OK,

it seems the bug is about how we expressed the filename. This works:

```
pptx(template = "/Users/xxxx/Downloads/doc.pptx")
```

But this failed:

```
pptx(template = "~/Downloads/doc.pptx")
```